# unexpected and esoteric behavior of += in python when combined with lists

Tags: python

the += for lists calls a different function compared to = this is very esoteric and hinders code readability

```
l=[]
l=l+"hello"
```

which returns `TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "str") to list`
whereas ;

```
l=[]
l+="hello"
print(l)
```

returns output `['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o']`

+= behaves similar to .extend here.
how to go about changing this so its easier to understand ?

Comment: You're correct that += for lists behaves differently than many new Python programmers might initially expect. The operation l += "hello" behaves more like l.extend("hello") rather than l = l + "hello".

Comment: *" how to go about changing this so its easier to understand ?"* In principle, subclass `list` and override `__add__` and/or `__iadd__`. It likely hampers code readability and maintainability, because anyone working with that code needs to keep track of whether they're using a builtin list or the subclass.

Comment: Changing what? How Python works? You're not going to change that.

Comment: Agreed, its a subtlety that I imagine is learned the hard way by trying to figure out why their code isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

For mutable types:

```
 a = a + b   # always creates a new object
```

and

```
 a += b   # mutates a if possible
```

are **not** equivalent! The latter is usually implemented as a mutation in that case. The same holds for most other such operators like `*=`, `|=`, etc.

For lists, `+=` is pretty much analoguous to `extend` and just like `extend`, it works with an arbitrary iterable (as you have found out using a `str`).

This kind of explains the observed behaviour:

```
 a + b
```

is a symmetric operation with a result. How are you going to determine the result type if the two operands have different types? Whereas

```
 a += b
```

is in itself asymmetric (the two operands have a very different semantic) and if no new object is created, no such type decision needs to be made.

Comment: Infix `+` is not really symmetric in Python. It is for numbers, but for strings and lists, `a+b` is different than `b+a`.

Comment: It can also allow mixed types, or even require them: for example `a+b` is invalid if `a` and `b` are both datetimes, but valid if `a` is a datetime and `b` is a timedelta.